# Calculating Laurent series for log function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Suppose I have the function:

$ f(z) = \frac{log(z+1)}{z^3} $

I need to find the Laurent series of this function to determine its order.

In this case we take $log(z)$ to be $ln|z|+i\arg (z)$

So we want to find the power series for $\frac{ln|z+1|}{z^3} + \frac{i \arg (z+1)}{z^3}$

$ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^{n-3}}{n} ]+ \frac{i \arg(z+1)}{z^3}$

I'm not sure how to incorporate the arg into the series though, any ideas?

EDIT: Log defined in my notes

[image]

Comment: Since $\log(1+z)$ is analytic on $|z|<1$, we can write $\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^n}{n}$ for $|z|<1$.

Comment: Laurent series converge in annular regions. Which annular region did you have in mind?

Comment: I don't think the region matters as long as we define it. My main confusion is the "arg" part of the equation which no one seemed to address, unless I'm missing something obvious which often happens. See my EDIT

Answer (score 1):

One may recall that, as $z \to 0$, by using the Taylor series expansion,
$$
\log(1+z)=z-\frac{z}2+\frac{z^3}3+O(z^4)
$$ giving the Laurent series expansion
$$
\frac{\log(1+z)}{z^3}=\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{2z}+\frac13+O(z)
$$as $z \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case log is the principle logarithm of $z+1$, and it needs to be written in terms of the natural logarithm and the argument of the complex number. Did you just set this part of the equation to $0$

Comment: @GregoryPeck You are welcome. The Taylor expansion in the beginning of the answer is true for *all complex numbers* such that $|z|<1$, which is the case as $z \to 0$...

Comment: Hi, I'm just wondering are you interpreting log as the natural log? See my EDIT, this might help you understand my confusion. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: @GregoryPeck No. I'm interpreting $\log$ as an analytic function over an appropriate complex region.